# Preserve object properties when assigned to a new value

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a object like this:

```
serviceSpec = {

   jsonData:{
       attachments: []
   }

};

function createJson(value){
    serviceSpec.JsonData = {sample: value}; //Line 1
    serviceSpec.jsonData.attachments.push('check'); //Line 2
}

createJson('test');
```

The problem is `serviceSpec.jsonData.attachments.push('check')` throws error saying `serviceSpec.jsonData.attachments` is not defined at Line 2

Apparently, at line 1, `serviceSpec.JsonData` is getting assigned to new value, but how do I preserve the object structure(with attachments) I defined above?

Comment: You're creating a new object on line 1.
It's all case sensitive. So it should be serviceSpec.jsonData

Comment: Erm: `ServiceSpec.JsonData` is different to `ServiceSpec.jsonData`

Comment: @Adriani6 Obviously that was a typo. My bad. Updating the question...

Comment: @evolutionxbox That was a typo. Please check the updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Object.assign:

```
var ServiceSpec={
 jsonData:{
  attachments:[]
 }
};

function createJson(value){
  Object.assign(ServiceSpec.jsonData,{sample: value}); //Line 1
  ServiceSpec.jsonData.attachments.push('check'); //Line 2
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I am doing `serviceSpec.jsonData = form2js('serviceSpecificationsForm', '.', true);` from a form to json library and assigning values. So probably `Object.assign` is the right choice

Comment: @satyadev yep its the easiest way copying multiple key:values into another object...

Answer (score 3):

Simply add a property to your Object instead of redefining it :

```
ServiceSpec.jsonData.sample = value; //Line 1
ServiceSpec.jsonData.attachments.push('check'); //Line 2
```

Comment: Your answer makes sense. Thanks